# Numbers in my Canon M50 Viewfinder

Tags: viewfinder

I have a brand new Canon M50 camera.  When I look through the viewfinder to take a picture, there is a 4 digit number in the bottom right hand of the screen. Right now it is 2909.  I have only taken 1 picture with my new camera.  So, what is that number?

Comment: Are you seeing that number while shooting, on playback, in the camera menus.. etc? We need a little more information to help you.  Best of all would be to upload an image of what you're seeing in the viewfinder, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

If it looks like this:

### [2909]

it is the estimated number of remaining shots your memory card has unused space to store with the currently selected settings.

If it looks like this:

### 29:09

it is the estimated amount of video recording time, in minutes and seconds, that your memory card currently has remaining room to record.

Normally this information is displayed near the top left corner of the viewfinder. However, you can use the menu to choose which informational items are displayed (and which are not). How to customize the 'viewfinder display format' is covered on the page with the heading 'Customizing Shooting Information Display' in the [*EOS M50
User Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300030545/01/EOS_M50_User_Manual_EN.pdf)

[image]

If you are using the INFO Quick Control Screen, the lower right corner has the estimated remaining number of images the card can hold displayed there.

[image]